# How to make git submodules use relative paths?

Tags: git

I have problems when recursively initializing submodules.

I have the following structure:

```
ProjectDir
    - submodule1_level1
         - submodule1_level2
         - submodule2_level2
```

When I call `git submodule update --init --recursive`, all level one submodules have relative path inside `submodule_directory/.git` file, whereas all the submodules of level 2 and below have absolute path there. How can I solve the issue?